# django module not found, cyclic.sh

Tags: python, django, deployment, devops

I tried to deploy my django app on cyclic.sh, i have the requirements.txt file in the root, and according to the logs, it is in fact downloading them on the server. but when i try to access the page, i get an error saying module not found 'django'.

**Initial logs:**

```
2024-01-07T23:37:49.675Z: Setting environment variables:
  CYCLIC_URL="http****************"
  CYCLIC_DB="lazy****************"
  CYCLIC_BUCKET_NAME="cycl****************"
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="serv****************"
  REACT_APP_API_URL="********************"
  CYCLIC_APP_ID="lazy****************"
2024-01-07T23:37:49.051Z: [CYCLIC] cloning...
2024-01-07T23:37:50.334Z: From https://github.com/AnshUjlayan/CourseOverflow
 * branch            7fd1626cd9c8a1595531ba8851d0b94a56977fee -> FETCH_HEAD
2024-01-07T23:37:50.394Z: HEAD is now at 7fd1626 idek
2024-01-07T23:37:50.399Z: [CYCLIC] Building...
2024-01-07T23:37:50.601Z: Build Configuration:
  Root Path: /server
  Output Path: /server
  Main file: server/wsgi.py
  Static Site: false
  Runtime: python3.11
  Branch: deployment
  Ref: 7fd1626cd9c8a1595531ba8851d0b94a56977fee

2024-01-07T23:37:50.604Z: [CYCLIC] verifying...
2024-01-07T23:37:51.346Z: [CYCLIC] using: python:3.11.2 pip:22.3.1 runtime:python3.11
[CYCLIC] building from: /server
2024-01-07T23:37:51.347Z: [CYCLIC] installing dependencies from /server/requirements.txt into /server
2024-01-07T23:38:02.767Z: [CYCLIC] bundling /server...
2024-01-07T23:38:07.459Z: 

[CYCLIC] packaging 166.65 MB...

2024-01-07T23:38:07.459Z: [CYCLIC] done packaging
2024-01-07T23:38:07.459Z: [CYCLIC] Deploying...
2024-01-07T23:38:21.846Z: deployed eu-west-1 -  14.337s
2024-01-07T23:38:21.847Z: SUCCESS

took 34.5 seconds
api deployed at:
https://lazy-gray-lizard-belt.cyclic.app
```

**the logs when i try to access the page:**

```
05:13:04.828

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/server/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
 [CYCLIC] ERROR: No response from server on port 3000
```

**this is my file structure:**

```
- server
  - api
  - build_files.sh
  - manage.py
  - requirements.txt
  - staticfiles
  - utils
  - server
    - __init__.py
    - __pycache__
    - asgi.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
```

Comment: Show us the contents of `requirements.txt`

Comment: Django==4.2.7
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djoser==2.2.2
google_api_python_client==2.108.0
PyPDF2==3.0.1


you can also inspect the whole project on https://github.com/AnshUjlayan/CourseOverflow/tree/deployment

here are the build options i have selected on cyclic:
Build Options
Change how your project is built and run.

Runtime
Python 3.11 (BETA)
Runtime for build and deploy 

Root Path
/server
The path to the project root (ex: /backend) 

Main File
server/wsgi.py
Your main file, relative to root path (ex: server.py)

i have no idea how to change lines I’m sorry